# When split method doesn't work correctly than I expect?

Tags: methods, split

```
     String s =  "    hello  "; 
     String[] strs = s.split(" ");
```

When I run this split method, I see that

```
      Strs[0] = " ";
      Strs[1] = " ";
      Strs[2] = " ";
      Strs[3] = " ";
```

Which makes sense so far.
However, even there is some " " after the word, "hello", java system did not creates any index for those of " " located after the word, "hello".

So, it eventually ended up to

```
Strs[0] = " ";
Strs[1] = " ";
Strs[2] = " ";
Strs[3] = " ";
Strs[4] = "hello";
```

Why is it??

Answer (score 0):

This is a prime example of the two overloading methods of java `split`.

1. `split(String regex)` -
   [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))
2. `split(String regex, int limit)` - [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int))

When you use `s.split(" ")`, the 2nd parameter `limit` is considered to be `0` by default, and this eliminates any dangling empty strings from result array.

If you want the dangling empty values, you have to explicitly pass `-1` as the parameter like `s.split(" ", -1)` resulting in `[, , , , hello, , ]`

The `limit` parameter actually controls the number of times this pattern `" "` is applied. The Javadoc documentation links I shared has the technical details for further reading.